# When i want to insert a new data into cartpaket table, i haved this error "Cannot assign "7": "CartPaket.toko_id" must be a "Toko" instance"

Tags: python, django, model-view-controller, foreign-keys

**This is my Toko Table**

```
class Toko(models.Model):
nama_toko = models.CharField(max_length=30)
username = models.CharField(max_length=30)
image_banner = models.ImageField(upload_to='toko')
lokasi = models.CharField(max_length=30)
deskripsi = models.CharField(max_length=30)
status = models.CharField(max_length=30)
boolean= models.BooleanField(default=0)

def __str__(self):
    return self.username
```

**This is my Product Table**

```
class Produk(models.Model):
nama_produk = models.CharField(max_length=30)
gambar = models.ImageField(upload_to='produk')
size = models.IntegerField(default=500)
deskripsi = models.CharField(max_length=200)
harga_resseler = models.IntegerField(default=0)
harga_agen = models.IntegerField(default=0)
harga_distributor = models.IntegerField(default=0)
harga_retail = models.IntegerField(default=0)
harga_hpp = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

**This is my CartPaket **

```
class CartPaket(models.Model):
customer_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
harga = models.IntegerField()
quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0)
total_berat = models.IntegerField(default=200)
subtotal = models.IntegerField(default=0)
total = models.IntegerField(default=0)
tanggal_pesan = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
kota_customer_id = models.IntegerField(null=True)
kota_pelapak_id = models.IntegerField(null=True)

toko_id = models.ForeignKey(Toko, verbose_name='toko', on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1)
produk_id = models.ForeignKey(Produk, verbose_name='produk', on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1)
def __str__(self):
    return self.customer_name
```

**This is my views.py**

```
                if CartPaket.objects.filter(customer_name=get_user, produk_id=pro.id,
                                        toko_id=get_toko.id).exists():
                cart = CartPaket.objects.get(produk_id=pro.id, customer_name=get_user,
                                             toko_id=get_toko.id)
                cart.quantity += jumlah
                cart.save()
            else:
                if jumlah != 0 or jumlah != '':
                    barang_distributor = Barang.objects.get(produk_id=pro.id, toko_id=get_toko.id) 
                    cart = CartPaket(produk_id=pro.id, harga=barang_distributor.harga_jual,
                                     toko_id=get_toko.id, customer_name=request.user.username,
                                     quantity=jumlah, kota_customer_id=kota_customer_id,
                                     kota_pelapak_id=kota_pelapak_id)
                    cart.total_berat = cart.quantity * cart.produk_id.size
                    cart.subtotal = cart.harga * cart.quantity
                    cart.save()
```

**This is post request information**
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OZhnU.png

**This is the error i haved**
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LYQja.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace toko_id by toko_id__id. This way you are saying that the value after "=" is the id of the toko_id instance.

toko_id is an instance, like you defined in your models. Its id is toko_id.id

Comment: yeah dude u are correct (but i should replace toko_id by toko_id_id without double underscore), my big mistakes are i want to create a new cartpaket, and fill the value of toko_id__username, when the toko_id__username is on the Toko table haha. cartpaket only have toko_id and toko_id_id from instance(Toko table). sorry for my english, i though my english so bad haha. ty mr jaff for answering my question. hope u havegood life :)